# How to change fonts dynamically between two views?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsuserdefaults

I have two UIViewControllers (ViewController and SettingViewController).

In SettingViewController I have 3 buttons that when pressed should change the font of the UITextView in the main ViewController.

I am using NSUserDefaults. However, it only works the first time or doesn't work at all.

I think the problem is that when I go back to my main view from the setting view the view is not reloaded.

How do I do this?

*SettingViewController.swift*

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

 var handWritingOption: String?
    var zapfinoOption: String?
    var systemOption: String?


@IBAction func handWritingPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        handWritingOption = "1"
        zapfinoOption = "0"
        systemOption = "0"

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(handWritingOption, forKey: "handWritingBool")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(zapfinoOption, forKey: "zapfinoBool")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(systemOption, forKey: "systemBool")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }

    @IBAction func zapfinoPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        handWritingOption = "0"
        zapfinoOption = "1"
        systemOption = "0"

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(handWritingOption, forKey: "handWritingBool")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(zapfinoOption, forKey: "zapfinoBool")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(systemOption, forKey: "systemBool")

    }

    @IBAction func systemPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        handWritingOption = "0"
        zapfinoOption = "0"
        systemOption = "1"

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(handWritingOption, forKey: "handWritingBool")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(zapfinoOption, forKey: "zapfinoBool")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(systemOption, forKey: "systemBool")

    }
}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var noteResult: UITextView!

var handWritingOption = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("handWritingBool") as? String
    var zapfinoOption = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("zapfinoBool") as? String
    var systemOption = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("systemBool") as? String

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadList:",name:"load", object: nil)
 }

func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
        println("Font Changed")

        if handWritingOption  == "1" {

            noteResult.font = UIFont(name: "ThinPencilHandwriting", size: 15)
        }

        if zapfinoOption == "1" {

            noteResult.font = UIFont(name: "Zapfino", size: 15)
        }

        if systemOption == "1" {

            noteResult.font = UIFont(name: "Papyrus", size: 15)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have added answer and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are using `Notification`. If Notification for `loadList` is not registered in ViewController when you change settings, it will not change anything. To make it happen make the following modifications.

`Step 1`: Remove use of Notification

`Step 2`: Add the following method in your `ViewController`

`Step 3`: Invoke it in `viewWillAppear()` as shown below

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // *** Load font value ***
    handWritingOption = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("handWritingBool") as? String
    zapfinoOption = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("zapfinoBool") as? String
    systemOption = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("systemBool") as? String

    // *** call setFonts ***
    self.setFonts()
}

func setFonts()
{
    if handWritingOption  == "1" {

        noteResult.font = UIFont(name: "ThinPencilHandwriting", size: 15)
    }

    if zapfinoOption == "1" {

        noteResult.font = UIFont(name: "Zapfino", size: 15)
    }

    if systemOption == "1" {

        noteResult.font = UIFont(name: "Papyrus", size: 15)
    }
}
```

It will set the fonts each time your view appears on screen.